# Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) not working VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code in **Sheet5(Support)**, Which is mentioned below.
But I can't figure-out where i am doing wrong.
**I am trying to do, If **Sheet5.Range("K3,K4,L4,M3")** change than, Sheet1 and ****Sheet4** **Range("K7").Value = Sheet5.Range("L5").Value**
When I change values in **Range("K3,K4,L4,M3")**, Then The **Sheet5.Range("L5").Value** autometically changed to another value.
For Example, Now **Sheet5.Range("L5").Value** is **"A"**, After modifications in any cell in **Sheet5.Range("K3,K4,L4,M3")**, The **Sheet5.Range("L5").Value** Become **"B"**. and now **Sheet1** and **Sheet4 Range("K7").Value** is equal to **A** instead of ****B**.
I need the value **B** after modification in **Range("K3,K4,L4,M3").**

My VBA code is below: -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ExitSub
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Sheet1.Unprotect Password:="123" 'CASH SALE
    Sheet4.Unprotect Password:="123" 'CREDIT SALE
    Sheet5.Unprotect Password:="123" 'SUPPORT

    If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("K3,K4,L4,M3")) Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitSub

    Sheet1.Range("K7").Value = Sheet5.Range("L5").Value
    Sheet4.Range("K7").Value = Sheet5.Range("L5").Value

    Sheet1.Protect Password:="123", AllowFiltering:=True
    Sheet4.Protect Password:="123", AllowFiltering:=True
    Sheet5.Protect Password:="123", AllowFiltering:=True

ExitSub:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("K3,K4,L4,M3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` - if this is true, then execution stops and `Application.Calculation` is never set to automatic. Move this line to the very beginning, before you change the calculation to manual.

Comment: Your code doesn't even act on the cells in the range where is would be supposed to be something modified... Iam afraid it is something wrong with the way you adapted it from something you found on internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always good to have error management in the SelectionChange events and be wary of exiting Subs without re-enabling events/display etc

For Example (untested):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ExitSub
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Sheet1.Unprotect Password:="123" 'CASH SALE
    Sheet4.Unprotect Password:="123" 'CREDIT SALE
    Sheet5.Unprotect Password:="123" 'SUPPORT

    If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("K3,K4,L4,M3")) Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitSub

    Sheet1.Range("K7").Value = Sheet5.Range("L5").Value
    Sheet4.Range("K7").Value = Sheet5.Range("L5").Value

    Sheet1.Protect Password:="123", AllowFiltering:=True
    Sheet4.Protect Password:="123", AllowFiltering:=True
    Sheet5.Protect Password:="123", AllowFiltering:=True

ExitSub:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You Mr. Tragamor,
Your Code is working, but I forgot to tell you that, When I change values in Range("K3,K4,L4,M3"), The Sheet5.Range("L5").Value autometically changed to another value.

For Example, Now Sheet5.Range("L5").Value is **"A"**,
After modifications in any cell in Sheet5.Range("K3,K4,L4,M3"), The Sheet5.Range("L5").Value Become **"B"**.

and now Sheet1 and Sheet4 Range("K7").Value is equal to **A** insteade of **B**.

Comment: I need the value **B** after modification in Range("K3,K4,L4,M3").

Comment: If the code works and answers your question (which is about error control), please mark as correct. You can always submit a further question with additions/alterations you want to make to the code and it's likely you would get more responses than now trying to alter the question parameters.

Comment: When I clicked on **Check Sign**, Its Pop Up an **unknown error**. I don't know why. and sir, I also modify my question with help of your answer. I need the value **B** after modification in Range("K3,K4,L4,M3"). Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is found on another resource and work for me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    On Error GoTo ExitSub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheet1.Unprotect Password:="''784c23704f733130'" 'CASH SALE
    Sheet4.Unprotect Password:="''784c23704f733130'" 'CREDIT SALE
    Sheet5.Unprotect Password:="''784c23704f733130'" 'SUPPORT
    Dim Xrg As Range
    Set Xrg = Range("L5")
    If Not Intersect(Xrg, Range("L5")) Is Nothing Then
    Sheet1.Range("K7").Value = Sheet5.Range("L5").Value
    Sheet4.Range("K7").Value = Sheet5.Range("L5").Value
    Sheet1.Protect Password:="''784c23704f733130'", AllowFiltering:=True
    Sheet4.Protect Password:="''784c23704f733130'", AllowFiltering:=True
    Sheet5.Protect Password:="''784c23704f733130'", AllowFiltering:=True
    End If
ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```